# Processing only modified files using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have got new requirement to be implemented using apache camel.

1. process the file without moving it
2. process the file only if it is modified
3. it is okay to process same file again
4. it shouldn't process new file.

As I am new to Apache Camel, I explored feature of file component and got some example and able to achieve first 3 points using below code.

```
from("file:C://inputFolder?idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}&noop=true")
    .to("file:C://outputFolder");
```

However unable to achieve the 4th point. Above code picks up the new file which being just created (Meaning created date and modified date is being same).

Could someone help me to achieve the 4th point (i.e. it should not pick up new file in that directory)

Comment: How would you expect to start this process? You can't populate the idempotent registry without processing the file the first time. If a new file was created, and then subsequently modified, would you want to process it then?

Comment: i wanted to start the process once app is deployed. During monitoring the directory if new file has been created, it shouldn't pick the file since the created and modified date and time is same. so only if it is modified it should be picked up. I am planning to handle it using processor to check if is new file before  directing to output directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to look at the time the file was created in Camel as I can see. Possible workaround here is to use renaming approach along with the `antInclude` option, e.g.

```
from("file:C://inputFolder?idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}&noop=true&antInclude=*.modified")
    .to("file:C://outputFolder");
```

In this case new file need to be created with another extension, such as `myfile.created`, and then renamed to `myfile.modified` after it was modified for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Since Camel 3.0 You can use [file-watch Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-watch-component.html). The solution can be similar to [Create snapshot of file when modified](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-watch-component.html#_create_snapshot_of_file_when_modified) example.

```
from("file-watch:C://inputFolder?events=MODIFY&recursive=false")
    .to("file:C://outputFolder");
```